# Start android app from dialog flow

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I'm android developer started with Dialog Flow. I need to run my application in the end of dialog flow conversation. Currently I have dialog flow and note js script working but I cannot run my android application from the dialog flow or firebase function.

What is the simplest way to do it? Can I run android app strait from js script? Can I use Deeplink for i?

Or I need Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) ? 
Any other options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to link the two at the moment would probably be to use an [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to notify devices that are owned by that user.

Answer (score 0):

Dialog flow is majorly a text-based conversational interface and it's best utilisation in app point of view would be designing Chat bot for your application. For instance, if you are working on Banking app, Chat bot can be implemented as an separate module and with the use of appropriate deep link based upon the questions users asks they can be navigated to the Page/content/reference users are looking for.
For bot response call it is vital to integrate AIConfiguration in your code with a project specific token code. Also, Dialog flow has an excellent facility where we can input of own questions and answers and train the agent accordingly. 
For example, if user inputs 'What's new in your Banking app?' we can add this question with it's answer in Dialog flow setup. 
Moreover, there are various applications or different usage of this feature like Suggestion chips, Deep link so on.
Follow the below link for additional information:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/setup